# How to make textview's background transparent when it is the child of the layout

Tags: android, background, textview, transparent

I have a textview in a layout and I set the click listener to the layout and layout's color was changed when the layout is pressed. However I want to set a textview's background to transparent but it can't. It take the window's background (the window's background is gray, my layout's background is white) instead of the layout's background.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="50dp"
              style="@style/TestLayout">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:text="Test"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In `styles.xml`

```
<style name="TestLayout" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/selector_test_small_layout</item>
</style>
```

In `selector_test_small_layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/s_pressed_layout" />
    <item android:state_hovered="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/s_pressed_layout"/>

    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/s_color_primary"/>
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/s_color_primary"/>
</selector>
```

**UPDATED:** Sorry about my xml is not fully enough. Tomorrow I'll update it correctly Y_Y. Now I dont have source code, only have picture

[image]

**UPDATED:** I included the more content in the styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    **<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/setting_divider</item>**
</style>
```

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:name=".TestApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        **android:theme="@style/AppTheme**">
....
</application>
```

Comment: post your layout xml..

Comment: please ask in details

Comment: ok let me update question

Comment: I updated my question @rafsanahmad007

Comment: @warlock please help me

Comment: @HienNguyen try `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` for your `textview`

Comment: It's my typo mistake :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked with the code added above, I could not see any issue at all. Could you please share the snapshot of screen to point out exact issue. Also you can try with setting the background="@null" on TextView.

Comment: I tried to recreate this case, please wait for my capture-picture

Answer (score 1):

When TextView.Background  is null, textView will be take, parent background

Comment: However, in my case, when I set the textview.background is @android:color/transparent. textview take the color of windowBackground instead of LinearLayout's background. So follow your guide, should I let the textview''s background is null ??

Answer (score 0):

Little bit old but hope so it helps somebody else

```
   <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/backfull</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>

    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme2" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@drawable/backfull</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/white</item>>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/backfull</item>
    <item name="background">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/ToolbarTitleTheme</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarTitleTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```